# trimming height of Masonite door

Tags: doors, structural

I have acquired a Masonite barn door, without hardware (the rail and roller wheels).   It is 84" tall, but the place where I need to install it has an obstruction (on the wall where the door would retract when in the open position) that's only about 84-1/2" from the floor.

[image]

Thus, regardless of what hardware I use, I'm going to need to trim some height off the door.   With one set of hardware, I'd need to trim about 3"; with the set I prefer to use, I'd have to trim off about 4-1/4"

My question: is it acceptable to trim this much height off the door ?  My concern is the structural integrity of the door.  Might I make it acceptable by reinforcing with steel plate ?  I'm pretty sure I'd want to trim the bottom, as trimming the top seems more likely to compromise structural integrity and also to look odd.   That bottom board is 8" wide.   Intuition tells me that trimming 3" is probably ok, but that 4-1/4", being slightly more than half its width, might be pushing it.   I also wonder if it'd be a good idea, and make trimming 4-1/4" acceptable, if I bolted pieces of metal plate to either side of that bottom board, after I cut it off.  That could also serve as a "kick" plate, making a virtue of a necessity.

[image]

Comment: Of course I could ask Masonite, but I assume I'd get a boiler-plate cover-your-**s answer of "any modification to the door would void the warranty".  Besides, I bought it used, so I doubt the warranty applies anyhow.

Comment: Is that bottom section hollow?  I've trimmed hollow core doors and replaced the solid rail at the bottom with good results.

Comment: I'm thinking a barn door would have less stringent structural concerns, being supported from the top rather than from the edge, like a normal door.

Comment: @JPhi1618 No I don't believe it's hollow.  For one thing, it has a groove mortised into it (for using that style of bottom guide, which obviously I'd forego unless I re-mortise it).  It also sounds solid to percussion.   It seems to be a solid frame, with that panel and the windows laid into it.